# Display result according to the age groups that are dynamically

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I want to display data according to the values like if member age is 18 it falls in the age group of 11-20 if age is 27 it falls in 21-30 if age is 16 it falls in 11-20 etc Remember that all age groups are dynamically here is the code `BEGIN

INSERT INTO #temp3
SELECT items from Split(@ageGroup,';')

INSERT INTO #FacilityWiseAges
     Select um.ID as memberId, um.groups as groups from (Select * from #temp3,udv_Members  )as um

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH,DOB,GETDATE())/12 <= SUBSTRING(@ldata, 0, CHARINDEX('-',@ldata))     
OR   DATEDIFF(MONTH,DOB,GETDATE())/12 >= SUBSTRING(@ldata, CHARINDEX('-',@ldata) + 1, LEN(@ldata))
```

FETCH NEXT   FROM detail
INTO 
@ldata
END 
CLOSE  detail;
DEALLOCATE detail;

```
Select Distinct  um.MemberName,
                 um.ID, 
                 um.BillingModeId, 
                 um.BillingModeName, 
                 um.MembershipTypeID, 
                 um.MembershipType,
                 DATEDIFF(MONTH,DOB,GETDATE())/12 as MemberAge,
                 SUBSTRING(fac.Name,CHARINDEX('-',fac.Name + '-')+1,LEN(fac.Name)) as FacilityName,
                 fac.MinimumAge as FacilityAgeFrom, 
                 fac.MaximumAge as FacilityAgeTo,
                 Convert(nvarchar(max),fac.MinimumAge) + ' - ' + Convert(nvarchar(max),fac.MaximumAge) as Default_FacilityAgeGroup,fages.groups

from udv_Members um 
LEFT JOIN #FacilityWiseAges fages on fages.memberID = um.ID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Bills] bill on bill.MemberID = um.ID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[udv_MembershipTypes] mt on mt.ID = um.MembershipTypeID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_BillingModes] AS bm ON bm.ID = [dbo].[udf_BillingModeByMembershipTypeID] (mt.ID)
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Bills_FacilityContractDetails] as fcb on fcb.BillID = bill.ID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Facilities_Contract_Details] as fcd on fcd.ID = fcb.ContractDetailID 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Facilities_Branches_Durations_Rates] fc on fc.ID = fcd.RateID 
INNER JOIN [dbo].tbl_Facilities_Branches_Durations as fdc on fdc.ID=fc.FacilityBranchGenderDurationID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Facilities_Branches_Genders] gb on gb.ID = fdc.FacilityBranchGenderID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Facilities_Branches] AS bab ON bab.ID =gb.FacilityBranchID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[udv_Facilities] AS fac ON fac.ID = bab.FacilityID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Member_Ledger] ledger ON ledger.MemberLedgerId = bill.MemberLedgerID
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_TransactionType AS t ON t.ID = ledger.TransactionTypeID
```

Drop table #temp3
Drop table #FacilityWiseAges`

Answer (score 0):

I assume by tagging asp.net, you are doing an sqlconnection sqlcommand.executereder call.

After doing the sqlcommand.executereader call, save the datareader which is returned into a gridview.datasource. Then call GridView.Databind() to actually send the command to the server and to receive the returned table.

To solve your question do the following:

Depending on your SQLcommand, the results you get are saved into the gridview like a excel sheet.

The result from your sql server is then interpreted and accessable in the following:

In this example I am using this table:

a b c d e f g

a b c d e f g

a b c d e f g

a b c d e f g

So, we have 4 rows and 7 columns.

With GridView.Rows(index of row).Cells(index of column).Text we can fetch the cell data as string. Example: GridView.Rows(0).Cells(2).Text returns c (Rows 1, Column 3). GridView.Rows(1).Cells(4).Text returns e (Row 2, Column 5).

Your select column order specifies the order of the columns. Knowing that, you can ask for the age. If we assume that a stands for the age, we can do:

```
If CInt(GridView.Row(0).Cells(0).Text) > 11 and CInt(GridView.Row(0).Cells(0).Text) < 20 Then
    //your code
end if
```

Continue the if statement for the other ages and specify your special code there.

Regards,

Niru